# I try to copy a file from a GCP instance to my local machine, but powershell gives me a "Permission denied: (publickey)"

Tags: kali-linux, scp, key-authentication, google-cloud, powershell

I created a GCP instance, and I created a private and public key on kali linux, I saved this key in the metadata of GCP, so I can access the instance through my kali machine. Then, I need to copy a file from this GCP instance into my local machine, so Im using powershell command:
scp -i C:\Users\mymachine\OneDrive\Desktop\ myprivatekey GCPUser@GCP_IP:/home/GCPUser/lastname.txt c:\Users\mymachine
But it gives me a publickey permission denied

Comment: Powershell didn't care about your public key: it's the server you're connecting to that does. It's, by the way, totally unclear why someone would use Kali, which is a special purpose non-development platform, for this kind of things, but I'm sure you have a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

Login to your GCP instance and run `journalctl -ru ssh.service` to see the most recent messages from `sshd`. The log message should include a reason why your public key authentication attempt was rejected.

The most common reason is that the `~/.ssh` directory or the `authorized_keys` file in it is not protected well enough. If the permissions would allow other users to write into the `~/.ssh` directory, `sshd` will ignore the `authorized_keys` file on the assumption that it might have been maliciously inserted by some other user.

If you are uncertain on how to change the permissions, please run `namei -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and add the output into your original question post. It should display the permissions of the file, the directory it's in and all the parent directories at once.

A good result should be similar to this:

```
namei -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
f: /home/GCPUser/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     home
drwxr-xr-x GCPUser  GCPUser  GCPUser
drwx------ GCPUser  GCPUser  .ssh
-rw------- GCPUser  GCPUser  authorized_keys
```